# Angular2 sub directory of umbraco

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, umbraco, subdirectory

I have an umbraco application. I want to integrate angular2 sub directory as a part of umbraco application. If some one type UmbracoURL/Inventory, I want to show angular2 Inventory application. Can any one provide me a solution please...?

Answer (score 0):

Is the Angular2 app a single page app? In that case you can integrate it as part of the Umbraco application.

You'll need to create a template in Umbraco with you Angular2 application, perhaps introduce a new documenttype called Inventory? Then create a new node called Inventory at root level in the Content tree, set the template to new Inventory template. And you should be able to access the angular2 app through the /inventory url.

If you want to use the content of a physical directory in Umbraco, you'll probably have to change the Umbraco/MVC routing

Comment: Thanks for you reply @Mark, I have an angular2 application with folder name Inventory which I want to keep inside Umbraco application and wants to get output from this Inventory folder when the URL is something like UmbracoURL/Inventory. Can you please tell me in a way of changing code manually(something that should let the URL recognise Inventory folder)? Because I don't know anything about umbraco but I need to put my angular2 folder inside Umbraco scripts folder and should make it workable.

Comment: It is not a single page application @Mark